# Decrypt following string

Tags: math, numbers, theory, modular

The matrix  A is 7  1
                 4  5

0-25 represent a-z in alphabetical order.
Find A inverse and hence decrypt the ciphertext  fact   .working modulo 26

Got this question in a test answer was supposed to be a word I got veho  can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse of

```
A = [7 1]
    [4 5]
```

computed in `Z_26` (the integers modulo 26)

is

```
A^-1 = [1   5]
       [20 17]
```

This is just the formula that, if

```
A = [a b]
    [c d]
```

Then

```
A^-1 =      1/      *  [d -b]
        (ad - bc)      [-c a]
```

To use this mod 26, you need to find the reciprocal of `ad-bc = 31 = 5`. This is just its multiplicative inverse, which is `21` (since `5*21 = 105 = 1` in `Z_26`).

```
Thus A^-1 = 21 * [5 -1]  =  21 * [5 25]  = [105 525] = [1   5]
                 [-4 7]          [22 7]    [462 147]   [20 17]
```

To test,

```
[1   5] [7 1] = [27    26] = [1 0]   (mod 26)
[20 17] [4 5]   [208 105]    [0 1]
```

It should be easy enough to use this inverse to decrypt -- just make sure to do all the arithmetic mod 26.

Comment: @zaph -- should be fixed now. Thanks for the correction. By an interesting coincidence `21` was still the inverse of the determinant.

Comment: Thanks guys I think there was a mistake with the question so can't remember exactly the numbers i got but the details was 31 and when I multiplied A by A-1 I got the identity  matrix checked my calculations  on the decryption  2 and got the same answer. Just knocked my confidence a bitime I thought  going into the test I was well prepared

Comment: I can say for certain about the downvote, but in general questions that don't show much  effort tend to attract downvotes. Your question would have been better received if you had shown your work.

Comment: Yeah it was an exam so don't have my work but I did give my answer for the question which would indicate that I attempted  the question myself.will bear that in mind for the next time. Thanks

Comment: Also I up voted your answer but I don't have enough rep for it to be displayed

Comment: @YarpoleCosgrave Thanks. You could always accept the answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I inverted

```
[ 7 1 ]
[ 4 5 ]
```

and came up with

```
[  5/31  -1/31 ]
[ -4/31   7/31 ]
```

I had a little help from http://matrix.reshish.com/inverCalculation.php.

Sorry, but I don't see how these mixed fractions could correspond to letters.